# How to _directly_ COPY files to "Program Files (x86)" folder in a Windows container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My question is specific to the Docker for Windows. The version I'm using is 17.03.1-ce-rc1-win3 (10625) on Windows 10 Pro x64.

I'm trying to create an image where I need to copy a folder into the "Program Files (x86)" folder in my container based on microsoft/dotnet-framework:3.5 image.

My Dockerfile is super simple ...

```
# escape=`

FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:3.5

COPY ["TestFolder", "C:\Program Files (x86)\TestFolder"]
```

Running `docker build`, I ended up

```
Step 2/2 : COPY ["TestFolder", "C:\Program Files (x86)\TestFolder"]
GetFileAttributesEx C:\Program: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

It looks like docker mistakenly stopped parsing the dest name at the first whitespace. However this `COPY ["<src>", ..."<dest>"]` is exactly the syntax for dealing the paths containing whitespace [(ref)](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/docs/reference/builder.md). And if I use any other folder name like "Foo Bar" instead, the COPY instruction just works as expected.

So my current workaround is using WORKDIR first to change the working dir to the "Prog...(x86)" folder and then doing COPY without explicitly giving the full dest path.

But I really would like to know if I did anything wrong with the COPY instruction.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe this is another instance of [issue 22874](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22874).

Comment: Thanks @BMitch for reporting this issue on github.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use double backslashes inside the braces

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore

COPY ["test.txt", "c:\\program files\\WindowsPowerShell\\Modules\\test.txt"]
```

It is interpreted as JSON.

Comment: Thanks a lot Stefan. Your answer works and makes perfect sense, although I can't understand why any other name containing whitespace just works without escaping.

Answer (score 0):

Change the backslashes with forward slashes as per below, double backslash no longer works for me but the below should do it.

```
COPY ["TestFolder", "C:/Program Files (x86)/TestFolder"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the backslashes with forward slashes as per below, double backslash no longer works for me but the below should do it.

```
COPY ["TestFolder", "C:/Program Files (x86)/TestFolder"]
```